# How do we store a string in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm learning javascript, xml, and html.  For a homework assignment, I need to retrieve some data from some nodes of a XML file, concatenate the data, and store the concatenated string in localStorage. I am having trouble in storing the concatenated string in localStorage.  I believe the issue is in these two lines -

var s_data = localStorage[students];
$("#clickme").text("Students' first names: " + s_data);

Can someone take a look and give me some tips on how to fix it? Thank you in advance for your help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <title>HWK</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
</head>
<body>
    <div id="clickme" onclick="startAjax()">Click me to see all the students' first names</div>
    <script>
    function startAjax(){
      $("#clickme").text("Calling server");
      $.ajax({url:"hwk.xml",    
      success:callbackFunction, error:errorFunction});
    }

    function callbackFunction(data,info)
    {
        var students = $(data).find("student first_name");

    try {
    if (students && students.length)
      {
        var s_data = localStorage[students];    
        $("#clickme").text("Students' first names: " + s_data);
              }
    }
    catch (e) {
      if (e != window["localStorage"])
        alert("No local storage. Should use cookie instead.");

    }
     }

    function errorFunction(data,info){
    $("#clickme").text("error occurred:"+info);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [setItem()](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#dom-storage-setitem) to set a value to the [localStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#dom-localstorage) and [getItem()](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#dom-storage-getitem) to retrieve it

Ex:

```
localStorage.setItem('mykey', 'somevalue')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d4c7a/)

Comment: I tried these in Fiddle but it did not work.  I did not get anything except for the "calling server" message.

Comment: @user2203774 which is the browser used

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage.setItem('your_data_key', 'your_data')`

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the data, you are getting the data that doesn't exist

I believe what you want is this

(You have to give a name to the variable in local storage, I'm giving it the name of students)

```
localStorage['students'] = students;
$("#clickme").text("Students' first names: " + students);
```

After this you can have your get if you want similar to what you had before

```
var s_data = localStorage['students'];
```

Comment: Hi. I used the two lines that you recommended and got the following: Students' first names: [object Object].

Comment: That's because students is an jQuery Collection and doesn't have a string representation because there can be multiple elements inside. Try for example students[0], this will give you the first element

Comment: I tried students[0] and it gives me: Students' first names: [object Element].  Since students is an jQuery Collection, is there a way for me to store it as a string in localStorage? (I'm sorry about my dump questions.)

Comment: Search for jQuery Collection to String in Google, you will probably find another stackoverflow page with the answer, I would give it to you, but I don't know it by heart :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anywhere in your code where you're storing something to `localStorage`. You're trying to retrieve `localStorage[students]`, but there's nothing there.

Note also that you can only store strings in `localStorage`. You're assigning a jQuery result to `students` at one point. Were you to try and store that in `localStorage` it would fail as it's an array of jQuery obects.

Comment: Hi. I thought this line will give me a string - "var students = $(data).find("student first_name");"  It gives me the concatenated data in a string.  Can you please let me know what I'm missing. I'm confused.

Comment: I think you'll find that gives you an array of XML nodes. You need to extract the text with `.text()`. I haven't seen your data, so I'm a little blind. However, the question was about storing data in `localStorage` which I think has been adequately answered by Arun. If you want to know about parsing XML with jQuery, ask another question.