# Remembering the outline after rebooting the user's computer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a basic online editing interface(works similar to Microsoft Outline) for coursework and i want the details on the outline to be stored if the user reboots the system. How could i go about that?

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Editor</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<header>
  <div class="navBar">
  </div>
</header>
  <textarea id="myTextArea">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent semper in nunc at mattis. Suspendisse metus augue, pellentesque finibus luctus dictum, tempor id nunc. 
  </textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: either you store data on the server or local storage

Comment: I want to store data on the server

Comment: So you need so submit data to the server and have code running on a server. Too broad to answer.

Answer (score 2):

By outline you mean textarea?
You would need a button and on click, that button should store the textarea to localStorage.

See more [Storing a string with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667582/how-do-we-store-a-string-in-localstorage)

@edit

Localstorage is going to save the info on the user browser only(if he changes his computer, the info would be lost), if you need to always keep it, you would need a running server to save the data.

See: [Step by step using Nodejs to run a server with MongoDB and Express](https://closebrace.com/tutorials/2017-03-02/the-dead-simple-step-by-step-guide-for-front-end-developers-to-getting-up-and-running-with-nodejs-express-and-mongodb)

Comment: How would i save the data on server instead

Comment: You would need to study a little about nodejs. I guarantee you that if you follow a simple CRUD with Nodejs, Express and MongoDB you would be able to do what you want. Or, you can also do the same with PHP and MySQL, its up to you.
The reason i suggested nodejs its because is trending atm, so its good to learn new things :)

Answer (score -1):

You have two options, you can either store the data in a database or in a file. Normally a database is better but if you only want to store the outline a text file would be better to not add unnecessary complexity.

I hope it helps!